# How to find max and min values within lists without using maps/SQL?

Tags: python, list

I'm learning python and have a data set (csv file) I've been able to split the lines by comma but now I need to find the max and min value in the third column and output the corresponding value in the first column in the same row.

This is the .csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj8tanwy1lr24yk/loan.csv?dl=0

I also can't use Pandas or any external libraries; I think it would have been easier if I used them

I have written this code so far:

```
f = open("loanData.csv", "r")
mylist = []
for line in f:
    mylist.append(line)



newdata = []
for row in mylist:
   data = row.split(",")
   newdata.append(data)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the csv?

Comment: A useful info would be if your data is made of numbers or text. For now your data is still text, thus "min" would mean the first in alphabetical order.

Comment: Use the `csv` module to read the file into a nested list.  Use `max` on the third column (list comprehension on nested_list[2]).

Comment: I have added the .csv file link, sorry for the missing info I am new to coding and have never posted here before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library for parsing your CSV file, and then just generate a list with the 3rd column values in it:

```
import csv

with open("loanData.csv", "r") as loanCsv:
  loanCsvReader = csv.reader(loanCsv)

  # Comment out if no headers
  next(loanCsvReader, None)

  loan_data = [ row[2] for row in loanCsvReader]
  max_val = max(loan_data)
  min_val = min(loan_data)

  print("Max: {}".format(max_val))
  print("Max: {}".format(min_val))
```

Don't know if the details of your file, whether it has a headers or not but you can comment out

`next(loanCsvReader, None)`

if you don't have any headers present

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.  The index would start at zero, so the third column should be 2.

```
min = min([row.split(',')[2] for row in mylist])
max = max([row.split(',')[2] for row in mylist])
```

Separately, you could probably read and reformat your data to a list with the following:

```
with open('loanData.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

mylist = list(data.split('\n'))
```

This assumes that the end of each row of data is newline (\n) delimited (Windows), but that might be different depending on the OS you're using.